# Rotation on ios 5.0

Tags: ios, ios5

I want to detect rotation in iPad for eg, iPad is rotated to 20 degrees or 270 degrees like steering wheel. What would be the good approach to do?

Answer (score 1):

i good approach would be to start reading the documentation on how to use the accelerometers and gyroscopes in iphone/ipad: just type 'accelerometer' or 'gyroscope' on Apple Developer Portal and you will get some references to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

using UIAccelerometer and monitoring continuous changes to the acceleration values will help to maintain a track of rotation angle.

Comment: The questions calls for the degree of rotation of the device, not the orientation, this would only provide discrete possibilities, not the continuous range required.

Comment: right... I went off topic for answer.. Updated now... thanks @JamesWebster

Comment: and for rotation you only need to consider Z.